# Dual boot and automatic time reset issue

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, 64-bit, date-time

I have a dual boot PC with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 64 bits. It was Ubuntu 32 bits before, but that was reinstalled with 64 bits recently. Since then, the hour is off by 2 hours when I boot either in Windows 10 or Ubuntu 64 bits.

Although I have 'set time automatically' enabled in Windows, it boots two hour behind. I have to go in that setting to disable and re-enable that feature to get the right time.

But, when I boot under Ubuntu 64 bits, it is also off by 2 hours and I have to reset it manually.

It's a if each OS was cancelling the time adjustment of the other. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Reset BIOS time once and check. and try changing CMOS battery also.

Answer (score 1):

As the computer starts, Press F2 or Delete to enter BIOS and check the time there.

If it's not showing correct time change it. Save and exit BIOS, check if it works.

Another reason can be a week cmos or motherboard battery, replace it.